# Constant not injected to config()

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to modularize my first angular project. Need to make my module views relative to this module. In example below i have sample main module, that require controllers module. I can inject `VIEWS_PATH` to controller, but no to  `config()`. As i know `constant` can be injected into `config()`. What is wrong with that ?

mainModule.js

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['app.main.controllers'])
.constant('VIEWS_PATH', 'js/modules/main/views');
```

controllersMain.js

```
angular.module('app.main.controllers', [])
.config(function($routeProvider, VIEWS_PATH) { // error
  $routeProvider.when('/hello', {
    templateUrl: VIEWS_PATH+'/hello.html',
    controller: 'HelloController'
  })
})
.controller('HelloController', function($scope, VIEWS_PATH) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello World!';
  console.log('VIEWS_PATH: '+VIEWS_PATH); // ok
});
```

Comment: it is pretty clear explained in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#constant-recipe (just read the whole section, you should get it then).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you defined your `VIEWS_PATH` constant in one module -`mainModule` and you're trying to use it in a different module - `app.main.controllers`.

You can define that constant in `app.main.controllers` module if you wish to use it in the configuration of that module.

```
angular.module('app.main.controllers', [])
.constant('VIEWS_PATH', 'js/modules/main/views')
.config(function($routeProvider, VIEWS_PATH) { 
  $routeProvider.when('/hello', {
    templateUrl: VIEWS_PATH+'/hello.html',
    controller: 'HelloController'
  });
});
```

But Constants from `app.main.controllers` module will work in `mainModule` as it listed as dependency in  `mainModule` like below.

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['app.main.controllers']);
```

For example, let's say we defined two modules - `MyApp` & `SomeModule`

```
var someModule =  angular.module('SomeModule',['someOtherModule']);
someModule.constant('SOME_CONSTANT','SomeValue');

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['SomeModule']);

myApp.constant('TEST_CONSTANT','Test');
myApp.config(function(SOME_CONSTANT){
  console.log("from dependent module "+SOME_CONSTANT);
});
```

With the above setup, `SOME_CONSTANT` from `SomeModule` can be used in `MyApp` but `TEST_CONSTANT` from `MyApp` cannot be used in `SomeModule`.

Here's a sample [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVpJjz) in action.

Comment: Do You know why `VIEWS_PATH` in my example is injected good in `controller()` ? I suppose if it works in `controller()` then should work in `config()`...